# Нужно создать функцию которая объединяет промежутки дат в массиве и возвращает его

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив временных промежутков(дата от-до включая крайние точки), нужно реализовать функцию, которая по заданному массиву будет возвращать массив объединённых промежутков, объедений все возможные к объединению промежутки в исходном массиве.

Например:

Было - [{05.01.22, 01.02.22}, {01.01.22, 02.02.22}, {05.03.22, 06.03.22}]

Стало - [{01.01.22, 02.02.22}, {05.03.22, 06.03.22}]

```
const dateFormat = (date) => {
    let mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    if (mm.length === 1) mm = `0${mm}`;

    let dd = date.getDate().toString();
    if (dd.length === 1) dd = `0${dd}`;

    let yy = date.getFullYear().toString();
    yy = yy.slice(2);

    return `${dd}.${mm}.${yy}`;
  };

  const merge = (dates) => {
    if (!dates || dates.length < 1) return [];

    const normalize = dates.map(({ from, to }) =>
      from < to ? { from, to } : { from: to, to: from }
    );

    const sortDates = normalize.sort(({ from: a }, { from: b }) => a - b);
    const result = [];

    let currentFrom = sortDates[0].from;
    let currentTo = sortDates[0].to;

    for (let i = 0; i < sortDates.length; i++) {
      const { to } = sortDates[i];
      const { from: nextFrom } = sortDates[i + 1] ?? { from: Infinity };
      const { to: nextTo } = sortDates[i + 1] ?? { to: Infinity };

      if (to < nextFrom) {
        result.push({ from: currentFrom, to: currentTo });

        currentFrom = nextFrom;
        currentTo = nextTo;
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  console.log(
    "Было",
    dates0.map(({ from, to }) => ({
      from: dateFormat(from),
      to: dateFormat(to)
    }))
  );
  console.log(
    "Стало",
    merge(dates0).map(({ from, to }) => ({
      from: dateFormat(from),
      to: dateFormat(to)
    }))
  );
```

Мучаюсь целый день можете хотя бы подсказку подкинуть)

Comment: Сколько в исходном массиве может быть промежутков? Возможна ли ситуация, когда в итоговом массиве будет более двух промежутков?

Comment: Привет! Этот массив неверный - [{01.05.22, 01.02.22}, {01.01.22, 02.02.22}, {05.03.22, 06.03.22}]. Такой тип данных не существует. Поправьте пожалуйста!

Comment: @Абдулазиз имеется ввиду это даты - строки, посмотрите в коде на функцию `dateFormat`. В данном случае это был всего лишь пример входных данных. (Псевдо кодинг проще говоря)

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Да может быть сколько угодно промежутков, 
вот еще пример 
Было - [{05.01.22, 01.07.22}, {05.01.22, 01.02.22}, {01.01.22, 02.02.22}, {05.03.22, 06.03.22}]

Стало - [{01.01.22, 01.07.22}]

Comment: @Абдулазиз 
Например:

Было - [{from: 05.01.22, to: 01.02.22}, {from: 01.01.22, to: 02.02.22}, {from: 05.03.22, to: 06.03.22}]

Стало - [{from: 01.01.22, to: 02.02.22}, {from: 05.03.22, to: 06.03.22}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил свой старый ответ, который был без учета пересечений интервалов, и объединил с ответом **@LaukhinAndrey**. Функция `mergeIntervals` возвращает массивы со строками дат формата `dd.mm.YY`, такими же как на входе.

```js
const intervals =  [
  ['05.01.22', '01.02.22'], 
  ['01.01.22', '02.02.22'], 
  ['05.03.22', '06.03.22'], 
  ['05.03.23', '06.03.24'], 
  ['05.03.21', '06.03.21'], 
  ['05.02.21', '06.02.21'],
  ['05.03.20', '06.03.23'],
  ['05.03.25', '05.03.26']
];

const dateToString = (date) => {
  const [dd, mm, yy] = [date.getDate().toString(), 
                    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(), 
                    date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2, 4)
                   ].map((str) => ('00').substring(0, 2 - str.length) + str);
return `${dd}.${mm}.${yy}`;
}

const stringDateDestructor = (str) => {
  return str.split('.').map((str) => +str);
}

const toUNIX = (dateArr) => {
   return +new Date(2000 + dateArr[2], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0]);
}

const isOverlapingIntervals = (target, interval) => {
  return target[0] <= interval[1] && interval[0] <= target[1]; 
}

const uniteIntervals = (a, b) => [Math.min(a[0], b[0]), Math.max(a[1], b[1])];

const mergeIntervals = (intervals) => {
  const result = [];
  intervals = intervals.map((int) => [toUNIX(stringDateDestructor(int[0])), toUNIX(stringDateDestructor(int[1]))])
                   .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
  result.push(intervals[0]);

  for (let i = 1; i < intervals.length; i++) {
let found = false;
for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
  if (isOverlapingIntervals(intervals[i], result[j])) {
    result[j] = uniteIntervals(intervals[i], result[j]);
    found = true;
  }
}
if (!found) result.push(intervals[i]);
  }

  return result.map((int) => [dateToString(new Date(int[0])), dateToString(new Date(int[1]))]);
}

console.log(mergeIntervals(intervals));
```

Comment: Мне интересна сложность `mergeIntervals`. Можно ли ее считать `f(n) = O(n*log(n))`?

Comment: _"если один интервал принадлежит другому, то он удаляется из массива"_ - есть сомнения, что это правильная логика. Например, отрезки [0, 4] и [3, 5]. Ни один из них не принадлежит другому, но результат ожидается [0, 5]

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey да, я мог не правильно понять задание, все таки пример в вопросе довольно куцый и я не учитывал "перекрытие" интервалов с последующим объединением.

Comment: A, все вижу в комментриях, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: сложность в худшем случае квадратичная.

Comment: в чем смысл такой конструкции `str.startsWith('0')? +str.substring(1, str.length) : +str` ? если приведение к числу можно сразу к `str` применять

Comment: @Grundy, потестил, вообще, видимо, никакого, думал будет `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Это булево объединение отрезков. Решение достаточно простое:

1. Сортируем отрезки по левой границе (по возрастанию).
2. Помещаем в итоговый массив первый отрезок.
3. Берем следующий отрезок и ищем перекрытие (наложение) с отрезками в итоговом массиве.
4. Если перекрытие найдено, объединяем. Если нет ни одного перекрытия, добавляем отрезок в итоговый массив.
5. Повторяем пункт 3 до конца массива.

```js
const isOverlap = (r1, r2) => r1[0] <= r2[1] && r2[0] <= r1[1];
const union     = (r1, r2) => [Math.min(r1[0], r2[0]), Math.max(r1[1], r2[1])];

function mergeIntervals(data) {
  let out = [];

  data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
  out.push(data[0]);

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    let found = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < out.length; j++) {
      if (isOverlap(data[i], out[j])) {
        out[j] = union(data[i], out[j]);
        found = true;
      }
    }

    if (!found) out.push(data[i]);
  }

  return out;
}


console.log(
  mergeIntervals([[1, 2], [0, 3], [4, 5], [10, 12], [7, 9], [6, 13]])
);
```

Я использовал обычные числа. Если вы будете сравнивать строковые представления дат, то важно соблюсти формат: ГГ.ММ.ДД. Но лучше оперировать с датами в числовом представлении (unix timestamp), или непосредственно с объектами `Date`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, понял суть, сейчас выполню эту функцию с помощью дат!