# Каким образом, лучше всего получить следующий результат?

Tags: php, php7, php8

Есть 2 массива

```
$s = [10 => 5, 50 => 5, 70 => 10];
$s1 = [12 => 1, 40 => 1, 60 => 10];
```

$s - это приходящие данные от пользователя, массив которого может не быть, а запись в бд необходимо занести.
$s1 - те данные которые пользователь прислал ранее, массива может не быть если пользователь ранее не отправлял, а запись в бд присутствует.

Суть массива, это отрывки в проценте. То есть вы случаете аудио, к примеру, только не всю дорожку проигрываете, а местами. Ключи в массиве - это процент старта, а значение это процент который пользователь прослушал начиная со старта, то есть от ключа.

Необходимо совместить 2 массива.

Каким образом лучше все получить данный результат.

```
[
10 => 5, //Во втором массиве 12 => 1, в сравнении из первого массива с 10 =>5. Не превышает значение, берем данные из первого
40 => 1, //Новый отрезок, который пользователь ранее не слушал
50 => 5, //Отрезок который пользователь прослушал в первый раз, во второй раз он его не проигрывал
60 => 20 // Тут пересечение, в первый раз старт = 70%, окончание на 80%. Во второй раз старт 60%, окончание на 70%(есть пересечение). Значит старт берем из второго (60%),а окончание на (10% + 10% = 20%), окончание получается на 80%
];
```

То есть найти пересечения, сравнивая 2 массива. Выполнить подсчет и сформировать новый массив.

Первый раз пользователь отправил массив, второй, третий и четвертый. Таким образом, будет известно суммарный объем который он прослушал.

Возможен такой массив

```
[0 => 100%] //В данном случаи сравнивать его нет необходимости, так как аудиодорожка проиграна целиком.
```

Comment: с первого взгляда надо во первых слить оба массива в один, отсортировать и ключи преобразовать в значения. потом уже заниматься объединением

Comment: Слили оба массива, отсортировали. А ключи для чего преобразовывать в значения?

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = [10 => 9, 50 => 5, 70 => 10];
$s1 = [10 => 15, 12 => 1, 40 => 1, 60 => 10];
$h = ($s ?? []) + ($s1 ?? []);
foreach ($h as $k => $v) {
    $h[$k] = $s1[$k] > $s[$k] ? $s1[$k] : $s[$k];
}
print_r($h);
```

Объединили 2 массива, ок. Далее перебираем массив, в цикле смотрим у какого из массивов наибольшее значение, меняем его.

Вопрос остается в том, как лучше всего найти пересечения. Если найдено пересечение к примеру

```
10 => 20 - то есть старт на 10%, окончание на 30%
20 => 15 - старт на 20%, окончание на 35%
Заменить их на 
10 => 25  - есть пересечение, ключ берем наименьший, а окончание наибольшее. Получается старт на 10%, а окончание на 35%
```

Comment: Это скорее дополнение к вопросу, чем ответ

Comment: И еще, стоит уточнить, что вы все-таки ищите. Если есть отрезки [10, 30] и [20, 35], то [10, 35] - это **объединение**, а не пересечение. Пересечение, в данном случае, будет [20, 30]

Answer (score 0):

За последнее время, эта задача встречалась на SO несколько раз, в разных формулировках.

Чтобы упростить саму постановку, надо представить данные отрезками:

```
[10 => 9, 50 => 5, 70 => 10] ---> [[10, 19], [50, 55], [70, 80]]
```

А сама задача представляется как булево объединение отрезков. Из недавних ответов на SO:

1. [Алгоритм, предложенный мною](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1427644/443096)
2. [Подход с заметанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1431271/443096), описанный @StanislavVolodarskiy